# I have added my script to the body.Whenever i run said script in CMD it closes the window.Why

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:start
color 0B
cls
set /p User_IP = Provide users IP address
set /p exp_time = Provide message expiration time in 
seconds
set /p Msg = Provide a message
set /p Confirmation = Confirm 1 or Cancel 2
if %Confirmation%==1(
GOTO :send_msg

)
if %Confirmation%==2(
GOTO :start

)

: send_msg
msg /SERVER:%User_ip% /TIME:%exp_time% "%Msg%"
pause
GOTO:start
```

//please overlook the simplicity of my work as I taught myself the basics of scripting.I wish to learn more and hope that this platform can assist me

Answer (score 1):

You've got three main problems with the code. First, batch allows spaces to be in variable names, so you've actually created variables called `%User_IP %`, `%exp_time %`, `%Msg %`, and `%Confirmation %`. Second, You need a space before the `(` in your `if` statements, or else you cause a syntax error. Finally, you have a space between `:` and `send_msg`, which means that the `:send_msg` label doesn't exist.

Additionally, you should add quotes around both things that are being compared in an `if` statement to prevent a syntax error if the user enters nothing, and you should have a default case for if the user enters something other than `1` or `2`.

```
@echo off
:start
color 0B
cls
set /p "User_IP=Provide users IP address: "
set /p "exp_time=Provide message expiration time in seconds: "
set /p "Msg=Provide a message: "
set /p "Confirmation=Confirm 1 or Cancel 2: "
if "%Confirmation%"=="1" (
    GOTO :send_msg
)
if "%Confirmation%"=="2" (
    GOTO :start
)
goto :start

:send_msg
msg /SERVER:%User_ip% /TIME:%exp_time% "%Msg%"
pause
GOTO :start
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified and improved version of your code

```
@echo off
:start
color 0B
cls
set /p User_IP=Provide users IP address:
set /p exp_time=Provide message expiration time in seconds:
set /p Msg=Provide a message:
set /p Confirmation=Confirm 1 or Cancel 2:

if %Confirmation%==1 goto send_msg
if %Confirmation%==2 goto start


:send_msg
msg /SERVER:%User_ip% /TIME:%exp_time% "%Msg%"
pause
GOTO:start
```

The first fix is that you added some of the echo / set text on line 7 instead of line 6 so it didnt recognize the command

The second problem is that you left a gap between var and equal sign on the set /p commands like here

```
set /p User_IP = Provide users IP address
```

should actually look like this

```
set /p User_IP=Provide users IP address
```

Also where you check the %confirmation% value you could just do this

```
if %Confirmation%==1 goto send_msg
if %Confirmation%==2 goto start
```

but even better is to do this (this makes all inputs that is not 1 goto :start

```
if %Confirmation% NEQ 1 goto start else goto send_msg
```

Comment: But if you want to use 

if %Confirmation%==1(
GOTO :send_msg

)

add a space before the ( so it looks like this:

if %Confirmation%==1 (
GOTO :send_msg

)

Comment: How this this different from my answer?

Comment: well if was typing an answer as you did and my code was a little simplified you did a great job just wanted to give my answer aswell

Comment: I greatly appreciate all of your advice

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the already provided answer by SomethingDark, I would suggest that you use [choice](/questions/tagged/choice) for your `Confirm`/`Cancel`, as it is significantly more robust for known entries. As for your less robust `set /p` commands, you should at least perform some sort of validation. *(I've included some very basic examples for you to refine further)*

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Color 0B

:StartIt
ClS

:AskIP
Set "User_IP="
Set /P "User_IP=Provide users IP address>"
2> NUL Set User_IP | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe"^
 /X "User_IP\=[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*"^
 1> NUL || GoTo AskIP

:AskTime
Set "Exp_Time="
Set /P "Exp_Time=Provide message expiration time in seconds>"
2> NUL Set Exp_Time | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe"^
 /X "Exp_Time\=[0123456789]*" 1> NUL || GoTo AskTime

:AskMsg
Set "Message="
Set /P "Message=Provide a message>"
If Not Defined Message GoTo AskMsg

"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 12 /N /M "1. Confirm, 2. Cancel."
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo StartIt
"%__AppDir__%msg.exe" /SERVER:%User_IP% /TIME:%Exp_Time% "%Message%"
Pause
GoTo StartIt
```